# how to check object name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have object and this object include objects too. It looks like:

```
  $scope.data = {
    tree : {
      name : 'oak',
      old : 54
    },
    dog : {
      name : 'Lucky',
      old : 3
    },
    system1 : {
      name : '',
      old : ''
    },
    baby : {
      name : 'Jack',
      old : 1
    },
    cat : {
      name : 'Fluffy',
      old : 2
    },
    system2 : {
      name : '-',
      old : '-'
    }
  }
```

As you can see this objects has obj name like - tree, dog, system etc. And I want to take only objects with name system, but this name can changes like system1, system123, system8. So I try to use this reg exp for ignore numbers

```
replace(/\d+/g, '')
```

But I can't reach this object name. I try this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item){conole.log(item)}) // but it shows content in obj not obj name..
```

How can I reach this obj name and distinguish this 2 system objects?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)`

Comment: You can even use `for .. in`

Comment: aha! so I guess in angular it looks like `angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item, key, obj){conole.log(key)})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass another param to the function like `key` to the `forEach` callBack Function. It is the key of the each object inside the object in your use-case.

Check the below example

```js
var items = {
  car: {
    a: 123
  },
  dog: {
    b: 234
  },
  system: {
    c: 456
  }
};
angular.forEach(items, function(item, key) {
  console.log(key);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var data = {
   tree : {
  name : 'oak',
  old : 54
   },
   dog : {
  name : 'Lucky',
  old : 3
   },
   system1 : {
  name : '',
  old : ''
   },
   baby : {
  name : 'Jack',
  old : 1
   },
   cat : {
  name : 'Fluffy',
  old : 2
   },
   system2 : {
  name : '-',
  old : '-'
   }
 }

 data = Object.keys(data) // get keys
 .filter(key => key.startsWith('system')) // filter keys starting with system
 .map(key => data[key]) // map to the values, returning a new array

 console.log(data) // and you have you array with systems
```

Comment: Please explain what you have done and why? Just putting working code is not enough

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys(myObject)`, that return an array of all the keys of the passed object, for istance:

```
var myObject= {
    cat : {
      name : 'Fluffy',
      old : 2
    },
    system2 : {
      name : '-',
      old : '-'
    }
}

var keys = Object.keys(myObject); // Keys will be ['cat', 'system2']
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass another parameter to angular foreach function to get the key name of the object like this:-

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item, key){ // Here key is the keyname of the object
    console.log(item, key);
});
```